# InvalidOperationException: Client found response content type of '', but expected 'text/xml'. The request failed with an empty response

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, asp.net-4.0

i just created one web application that deal with WCF Service. Now in linqpad5 i just load all methods from this class. and just write to just test output received from this service or not.

here is my pc's screenshot:

[image]

but at time of executing small program i just got this error like :

```
InvalidOperationException: Client found response content type of '', but expected 'text/xml'.
The request failed with an empty response.
```

for more information i just include hosted wcf service config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" defaultLanguage="c#" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
  <pages validateRequest="false" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="LargeWeb" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="RestServiceImplClient">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="LargeWeb" contract="IRestServiceImpl" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WebHttp">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="http" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".svc" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

what going wrong here... please help me out of this guys...

**update**

this service working with iis browsing :

[image]

Comment: I checked your configuration file and found no problem. I suspect it may be a problem with the WCF service. Can your service run normally?

Comment: ya while browsing with iis its working like charm. see update section.

Comment: I think this may not be a problem with the WCF service, but may be related to linqpad5. Can you use c# to call the WCF service?